# If a WHOIS search returns 428 domains on the nameservers for that domain, does that mean that server is hosting 428 domains?

Tags: dns, domain, hosting, nameserver

I've just done a WHOIS search on whois.sc for our company domain and the nameserver section says that our nameservers "(has 428 domains)".

Does that mean there are 428 domains hosted on the same server as ours? The reason I ask is because we pay a hefty fee (more than enough for a dedicated server) for our hosting each month and I want to make sure our company isn't paying stupid money for a shared server, and if they are I'm going to have a word with the guys that run our site.

Comment: Instead of looking at whatever data, why not just investigate the hosting package. It will have the relevant information.

Comment: All a WHOIS returns is registration information. You might be mixing up hostnames with domain name registration. You can set an almost limitless amount of hosts that point to an IP address but hosting costs have nothing to do with that. You are best served by checking your hosting package. Right now you might be simply looking for large numbers of something you don’t really understand and then are getting outraged.

Comment: We don't have access to view our hosting package, the guys that built our website just charge us a monthly fee for 'hosting' which is why I asked.

grawity answered my question anyway

Comment: Ah, so you’re contracted with a web design agency or whatever. That’s expensive, yes. Whether it’s worth it is a question you must answer yourself. Consider ongoing maintenance, backups, dealing with security breaches, ...

Answer (score 2):

> Does that mean there are 428 domains hosted on the same server as ours?

**Don't confuse web hosting and DNS hosting.** They are independent services and usually hosted by separate servers. They have separate administration and *quite* different resource requirements.

When the 'whois.sc' website talks about *nameservers*, it strictly means those which host your DNS zone (basically: IP address mappings for the domain and subdomains). It is common for this DNS data to be hosted on a shared server owned by the domain registrar (possibly even holding tens of thousands of zones), and many registrars provide this as a free service.

However, that's completely independent from where the domain's own services are kept. It doesn't tell you anything about whether the website runs on a beefy dedicated server or on a potato.

Instead, to get a guess whether the *web* server for your main domain is shared or dedicated, you can look at the "`IP address:`" line slightly below in the same whois.sc result page. If whois.sc has seen other domains pointing to the same address, it will say "X other sites hosted on this server". If it hasn't seen any *yet*, it'll say "is hosted on a dedicated server".

Comment: “Don't confuse web hosting and DNS hosting.” Bingo!

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this, I see now they are only hosting our .com and .co.uk domain on this server.

The reason I asked is because we are getting massive fluctuations in server response time, it's still something I need to bring up with them as there's something not right but it just shocked me when I saw the 428 domains.